# Azure Functions Node v4 - Error updating CA certificates in container

Tags: node.js, docker, azure-functions

I'm trying to update our Node.js Azure Function to version 4. I have set FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION=~4 and --linux-fx-version "Node|16". After using our deployment pipeline, I encounter an error in the container. I get the same error when deploying locally from the container.

```
Error: ./containerlaunch.sh: line 6: update-ca-certificates: command not found
```

Our Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:focal

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y \
    ca-certificates \
    curl \
    apt-transport-https \
    lsb-release \
    gnupg \
    python3-pip \
    jq && \
    curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | bash && \
    apt-get install -y nodejs && \
    npm install --global azure-functions-core-tools@4 --unsafe-perm true && \
    npm install -g typescript && \
    python3 -m pip install --system azure-cli && \
    apt-get clean && \
    apt-get autoremove --yes && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/{apt,cache,log}/

ENV FUNCTIONS_CORE_TOOLS_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT=1
ENV DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_INVARIANT=1

COPY startup.py /

....

ENTRYPOINT [ "/startup.py" ]
```

I don't have access to modify containerlaunch.sh, as it seems to be managed by Azure Functions.

What could be causing the update-ca-certificates: command not found error, and how can I resolve it? It always pops up when trying to start the function. Locally I can run the functions in Docker without problems, only in Azure the errors appear.

Thanks & Regards

Comment: Try adding this command - RUN update-ca-certificates by referring the answer in this thread- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76072086/azure-functions-node-v4-error-updating-ca-certificates-in-container By banoth ravinder and Jobin James

Comment: @SiddheshDesai Hi, thanks for your reply. Unfortunately it doesn't fix the error. But I have seen that the function can still be started.

Comment: Try this npm install -g typescript && \
    RUN apt-get install -y ca-certificates
    python3 -m pip install --system azure-cli && \ Try adding this RUN apt-get install -y ca-certificates or directly run apt-get install -y ca-certificates or sudo apt-get install -y ca-certificates in your container to install ca certificate and check?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the underlying distribution you will have either update-ca-certificates or update-ca-trust.  Maybe in this case "update-ca-trust" should be used instead.